# How to delete certain rows from MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, database, row

Okay, so my database looks something like this: 
 `MapID` 
 `h-1` 
`h-2` 
 `s-1`
 `s-2` 
 What I'm trying to do is delete rows where the MapID begins with **h**, and not the rows that begin with anything else (I have multiple alphabet letters to distinguish which type of data is in that row). How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM map_table where mapid LIKE 'h%';
```

See documentation for [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like).

Answer (score 1):

if you don't like using like you can use a string function like so

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE LEFT(MapID , 1) = "h";
```

this should be faster if you have an index on MapID

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09e7bb/1)

Answer (score 0):

You would just do:

```
delete t from table t
    where t.mapid like 'h%';
```